# What is the best way to find relatively prime number to another?

Tags: algorithm, math

I'm trying to create RSA algorithm by myself, so I'm on the step when I need to find relatively prime number to another. Is there a better way than check every number for GCD(a, b) == 1? Also this number better be big, will be good if algorithm could find relatively prime "from the end".

Comment: You could use integer factorization to find all factors for `a` and generate a `b` without these factors.

Comment: @jabaa Could you explain this in details if you don't mind?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization

Comment: Where does number `a` come from? Do you generate it or is it an input?

Comment: @jabaa I got 'a' number from previous operation(result of phi function).

Comment: That means you already have the prime factors of `a`? You need them for the phi function. Then you can generate a random relative prime number

Comment: @jabaa yeah I've got prime factors of 'a', I just don't save them(I need only amount). How can I generate relative prime to 'a' with using 'a''s prime factors?

Comment: Generate random prime factors p1, ... , pn that are not prime factors of `a` => `gcd(a, p1 * ... * pn) == 1`

Comment: it's not *relatively* prime numbers you need for RSA, it's actual primes. If you have an integer `n` then`n+1` is guaranteed to be relatively prime to `n`, but that's not very useful.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Maybe it's not useful for RSA, but it answers the actual question: `gcd(a, a + 1) == 1`

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: I suspect the OP is looking for a choice for the encryption exponent `e`, so they need something relatively prime to `(p-1)(q-1)`.

Comment: It feels like you posted this much too early in your investigations, and is really a matter of "this is what the web is for". Loads of people have written blog posts and both programming and maths articles about efficient GCD algorithms: search for those, read through them, try several, and then based on your needs decide which one to use. Right now, this post is essentially just asking for opinions.